# Is there a way to speed up VBA by grabbing all file information with 1 grab?

Tags: performance, vba, file, loops, dir

I have some code that uses an array with network path location and then pulls information about files in each path.

The problem is the code is VERY slow. I have realized that the main problem is reaching over the network 3 times for each file. 1 time to find the file name, a 2nd time to grab the last modified file date and a 3rd time to capture the file size. IS there a way to grab all this info with one sweep to speed things up?
Thank you :)

```
 For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        file = Dir(x(i))

    While file <> vbNullString
                        fileModDate = FileDateTime(x(i) & file)
                        FILESIZE = FileLen(x(i) & file)
    Wend
Next i
```

Comment: Your could use a [FileSystemObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat(v=vs.84).aspx) from the *Scripting Runtime* library.

Comment: I tried to use a FileSystemObject. No speed improvement at all. Still have to do 3 file grabs over the network.

Comment: Please share how you did with FileSystemObject.

Comment: Set F = fs.GetFile(fullfilepath)
fileModDate = F.DateLastModified

Comment: umm, these makes two network queries, right? But the third, `FILESIZE = F.size` should be locally available now, am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it seems like the information is again fetched over the network. Just tried it with my CD drive... You are right.